# Method for splitting string and concatenate it after formatting

Tags: java, string, jsp, string-concatenation

I want to split a string coming from a log file, format the split string, concatenate it again, then print the formatted string again. Currently, the code is just printing file line by line while the rest that I want is remaining.

My code is:

```
   try                
   {
      String strpath="/var/date.log";
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(strpath);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String ch;
      String[] Arr;
      do 
      {
        ch = br.readLine();
        if (ch != null)
        out.print(ch+"<br/>");   
      } 
      while (ch != null);
      fr.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    out.print(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Contents of log file:

```
[1322110800] LOG ROTATION: DAILY
[1322110800] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1322110800] CURRENT HOST STATE: arsalan.hussain;DOWN;HARD;1;CRITICAL - Host Unreachable (192.168.1.107)
[1322110800] CURRENT HOST STATE: localhost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.06 ms
[1322110800] CURRENT HOST STATE: musewerx-72c7b0;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.27 ms
[1322110800] CURRENT HOST STATE: sharepoint2;DOWN;HARD;1;CRITICAL - Host Unreachable (192.168.1.100)
```

I want to split this file per line on "]" and then get content in square brackets, format it in long date time and then concatenate it with the remaining line and print it.

This should be done with every line of the file.

This will give the formatted date:

```
String dat="1324649468000";
Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(dat));
```

Comment: Is there some reason you want to reformat an already-formatted log statement rather than change the format provided by your logging configuration?

Comment: i want to format its date as it is in just 10 digit format it will be change to date time format

Comment: I guess I still don't understand. Do you need to retain the existing format? If you don't need the existing format, just update the logging configuration to provide the date format you need.

Comment: how can we update the logging configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code snippet to do that conversion:

```
String line = "[1322110800] LOG ROTATION: DAILY";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(m.group(1)) * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    line = m.replaceFirst('['+ sdf.format(dt) +']');
}

System.out.println(line);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[11-24-2011 00:00:00] LOG ROTATION: DAILY
```

Comment: i want to format all the dates of log file does this method is for all log file or is it for only first line?

Comment: This is of course for all the lines :) All you needed to do was put this code inside your while loop assuming you're reading every line of log file in variable `line`. Just keep `Pattern.compile` before the while loop.

Comment: @ anubhava  you are awsome man it works very excellent but it is showing year 1970??

Comment: It is showing 1970 because timestamps in your log file are **seconds since Epoch** not the milliseconds as expected by Java `Date` class. You need to multiply that number by 1000 to show correct Java date. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: i just want it as it is "[Fri Aug 31 19:04:40 EDT 2001] LOG ROTATION: DAILY"  but want to omit "EDT 2001" from it then what should i do ??

Comment: is it possible to multiply it here in your code to get the right Year value?

Comment: Yes multiplication is done in the code itself, please check my updated answer above. Also for printing `Date` in your desired format you can use SimpleDateFormat class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Let me know if you need code sample for that as well.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply i will manage it one last thing that if i want to show this data in this format like,                         December 28, 2011 09:00  

Informational Message[12-28-2011 09:25:29] Event broker module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' deinitialized successfully.
Informational Message[12-28-2011 09:25:29] ndomod: Shutdown complete.
Informational Message[12-28-2011 09:25:28] Successfully shutdown... (PID=3791)                                                                                December 27, 2011 17:00  

Host Down[12-27-2011 17:07:38] HOST ALERT:

Comment: Alright, please see my updated answer for the date format you wanted. Hope that helps.

Comment: i am having error in your updated code that "SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type"??

Comment: You need to put `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` on top to use this class. btw you should be using some IDE like Eclipse that does it automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your cooperation you have really very strong skills ! lets check the image i attached to my first post

Comment: pic is not getting attached to the post so i am telling you ...   result would be look like as,

Comment: pic is not getting attached to the post so i am telling you ...   result would be look like as, please mail me your id i will mail you snapshot

Comment: U can email me `anubhava[AT]aol[DOT]com` and pls mark this answer as accepted if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

If your file always have this type i think this will help you

```
public static long stringToLong(String ch) {              
    String temp="";
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length();i++)
   {
       if(ch.charAt(i)=='[')           
           continue;
       if(ch.charAt(i)==']')
           break;
       temp+=ch.charAt(i);       
   }
    return Long.valueOf(temp);
   }



Date d = new Date(stringToLong(ch));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scanner and regular expressions to do this.

```
Pattern logPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[([^\\]]*)\\](.*)$");
Scanner input = new Scanner( new File( strpath ) );
while ( input.hasNextLine() ) {
   String line = input.nextLine();
   // checkout how to parse a string with Pattern (obtain matcher) and get the arguments
   out.println( line + "<br/>" );
}
```

And don't forget to properly close the input and output.

Comment: i am using my code in jsp page .. . what file would i have to import for your code and it would print the file after formating the date?